Geometrynode voxelizing scale issue
I'm trying to using geometry nodes to voxelize a model at a small scale. There is an abrupt cutoff around the scale of 0.005m at which the nodes no longer render the full model, but only portions of it. I tried scaling the whole model up to avoid errors with small values, to no avail. Below are images of the model as well as the geometry node logic.


